# autotools undefined reference error

Tags: c++, namespaces, autotools, undefined-reference

My project is structured like this:

```
ProjName/
    | configure.ac
    | Makefile.am
    | src/
        | Main.cpp
        | Main.h
        | Extra.cpp
        | Extra.h
```

Both Main and Extra are classes within the same namespace `MyNamespace`. Even though `Main.h` includes `Extra.h` I'm getting a linker error:

```
in function MyNamespace::Main::Main():
undefined reference to MyNamespace::Extra::Extra()
```

I've made sure that all class are encased in

```
namespace MyNamespace { ... }
```

as well as adding `using namespace MyNamespace` to `Main.cpp` and the constructors for both classes are correct.

The only thing that seems to solve this problem is adding `#include "Extra.cpp"` to `Main.cpp` but this would just defeat the purpose of using a header file at all, and will get extremely tedious when I add more files to the project.

**Edit:**

`Makefile.am` looks like:

```
bin_PROGRAMS= ProjName

ProjName_CPPFLAGS= -I$(top_srcdir) -I$(top_srcdir)/src
ProjName_SOURCES= src/Main.cpp Main.h
```

My project uses the Ogre3D library so there are also some Ogre specific things. I've tried adding the cpp and header file to `ProjName_SOURCES` and running `./bootstrap && ./configure && make` but I then get an error, something like:

```
No rule to make .deps/src/ProjName-Extra.Po
```

Or something along those lines (I'm on the phone at the moment).

Comment: Show your `Makefile.am` - are you compiling both `Main.cpp` and `Extra.cpp`?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with autoconf/automake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the source files correctly.  Try:

```
ProjName_SOURCES = src/Main.cpp src/Extra.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

This means **Extra.cpp** is not compiled and linked to your executable. Check your makefile.